# How can i make a UIButton with multiple color text a titleLabel in ios 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uibutton, nsattributedstring

Lets go straight to the point. I need a `UIButton` with two colored text. I know i can do this using `NSAttributeStrings property but it does not work in ios 5.

So how can i make it for `ios 5.0`?

Till now i have done this:

```
NSDictionary *firstAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]
                                  };
NSDictionary *secondAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]
                                   };

NSString *club = NSLocalizedString(@"club_button_concat_text", @"club_button_concat_text");
NSAttributedString *myString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:club attributes:secondAttributes];
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this will not be possible for iOS < 6. As a workaround you can create a custom view and using `drawRect:` method, draw button UI. Use CoreText to draw the attributed string. Override the `touchesEnded:` method to detect button touch events.

For core text drawing you can follow this [link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/). For drawing button, check open source projects which already do this! Hope this helps..

Cheers!

Amar